# How to retrieve parameters from web.cml in JAX-RS service in application scope?

Tags: tomcat, jax-rs

my problem is twofold: first I need to access a context parameter from the web.xml in my JAX-RS application. Second I need to do it only once for the application (application scoped). I am deploying to tomcat6, if that makes any difference.

- Question 1: how do I create an application scoped 'bean' in JAX-RS
- Question 2: in that bean, how would I access the context-param from my web.xml?

Cheers!

This does NOT seem to work:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.resource.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class ApplicationBean 
{
    @Context
    HttpServletRequest request;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: @Singleton annotation would make your resource one

Q2: you can inject the request object in your JAX-RS resource and get any context param from there:

```
@GET
@Path("/my")
public String get(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    request.getServletContext().getInitParameter("my-param");
```

or

```
@Context 
HttpServletRequest request;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    request.getServletContext().getInitParameter("my-param"); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful. Is there any method that is called in the class marked `code`@Singleton`code` that is always called on construction? Or do I need to use something like `code`@PostConstruct`code`?

Also: in the `code`@Singleton`code` class, is there any way of getting to the Context-Param values without having a request?

Comment: You should be able to inject @Context HttpServletRequest as a class attribute which you can then use in a \@PostConstruct method, but be careful since the scope is application it may not reflect the current actual request in subsequent calls.

Comment: I tried your solution. The question is edited accordingly. It didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: What didn't work? @PostConstruct requires CDI or EJB. Are you using a full Java EE server? If you're using just a web container like Tomcat then this won't work indeed...

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you. Any other options you can think of?

Comment: by default JAX-RS will create a new resource instance for each invokation and I don't think you can change that behavior w/o CDI or EJB...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I though that behavior could be controlled using the `@Singleton` annotation?

Comment: @Singleton is either from javax.inject (CDI) or javax.ejb (EJB), both of which require EE I'm afraid... If you can't switch to GlassFish you can take a look at tomEE.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll do that.